# Access data value from data

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to assign a string value to a variable based on a boolean variable.

Following this code I got:

[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'check' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'check' of undefined

and so on.

```html
<v-text-field
  ...
  :placeholder="placeholder"
  ...
></v-text-field>
```

```js
data: () => ({
   ...
   check: false,
   placeholder: this.check === false ? "Hello" : "Bye"
}
```

I expect the placeholder changes its content based on the check variable

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `placeholder` as a computed property like :

```
computed:{
       placeholder(){
            return  this.check === false ? "Hello" : "Bye";
         }
   }
```

Comment: It actually worked, here the code:
placeholder: {
   get() {
    return this.check === false ? "" : "Enter a location";
   },
   set() {}
    } 
However I still don't understand the why of this behaviour.

Comment: Besides, I found another way to solve it by calling a method and do the `this.placeholder: this.check === false ? "Hello" : "Bye"` and it worked. I guess is related to the Vue life cycle